# Joomla Plugin translations dont take effect

Tags: plugins, joomla, translation, joomla3.0

I'm having a small problem and I cant figure it out...

I've downloaded the plugin and translated the `.ini` language files to my language. **BUT** when I uploaded the files directly to `administrator/language/es-ES` folder it doesnt translate the plugin...

What am I doing wrong?

Also tryed to upload to `frontend/language` folder, still nothing changes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, downloaded Localise and fixed the error made during the translation. Awesome plugin.